# Smoothness of derivative in both variables simultaneously

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

For a proof in Differential Geometry I need the following to be true. However let me know if it is not the case and you have a counter example.

Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function defined on an open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$. I would like to show that the function
$$
F:U\times\mathbb{R}^m\ni(p,x)\mapsto D_pf(x)
$$
is smooth, where $D_pf(x)$ denotes the total derivative of $f$ at the point $p$ evaluated at the vector $x$.

It is clear that for a fixed $p$ the function $x\mapsto D_pf(x)$ is smooth, because it is linear. How can you show that for fixed $x$ the function $p\mapsto D_pf(x)$ is smooth? Do these two steps even help in the proof that $F$ is smooth simultaneously in booth variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for $f$ to be smooth implies that the function $p\in U \mapsto D_pf \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is smooth. If you fix a vector in $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$, this says that $p \mapsto D_pf (v)$ is smooth too (think of $(D_pf)_p$ as a smooth family of matrices parametrized by $p$).

To elaborate a bit, just write $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ in coordinates. Then in coordinates, $D_pf = \begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(p) \end{pmatrix}_{1\leqslant i \leqslant n, 1\leqslant j \leqslant m}$

Comment: Could you elaborate how precisely your definition of smoothness implies that the function $p\mapsto D_pf$ is smooth? I defined a function to be smooth, if all partial derivatives are smooth.

Comment: I edited my answer with an expression in coordinates of $D_pf$. This should be clear with what you stated in your comment.

Comment: @Proxava your definition is a coordinates one, while my definition is a coordinate-free definition. But they just say the same thing.